# while i am trying to run the app using npm start ,it shows me an error . How can i fix it?

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules

souad.llddnn@gmail.com

> client@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

"webpack": "4.41.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

C:\Users\user\there-is-hope\Algeria-Chain\node_modules\webpack (version: 5.77.0)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

I tried everything but i still stuck with same problem , please anyone who pass through this problem and he knows how to fix it let me know